# No command 'ember' found

Tags: ubuntu, npm, ember-cli, bash

Seems like I messed up with my ember-cli install.
I had installed the npm using sudo, but after reading  some issues with ember-cli and sudo on npm I went for uninstall and reinstall following the instruction here https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814.

Now I have installed ember-cli through `npm install -g ember-cli` but when I do an `ember new <name>` I get

> No command 'ember' found, did you mean:
>
> Command 'enber' from package 'asn1c' (universe)
>
> ember: command not found

I can do which node

> $ which node
>
> /home/[user]/local/bin/node

and which npm

> $ which npm
>
> /home/[user]/local/bin/npm

, but I can see that ember exists in the following path that is installed:

> npm install -g ember-cli
>
> /home/[user]/npm/bin/ember -> /home/[user]/npm/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember

Any ideas how to get ember command  working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure `/home/[user]/npm/bin` is in your shell's path. You can `echo $PATH` to see if it's included.

For Bash:

Add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

```
PATH=/home/[user]/npm/bin:$PATH
```

And then restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc`

For ZSH:

Add this to your '.zshrc`

```
path+=('/home/[user]/npm/bin')
```

And then restart your terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc`

You will need to replace `[user]` in the paths with your user name on your computer.

Comment: path+=('/home/[user]/npm/bin')
what does this do?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). It gives you power to easily manage your node.js/npm versions without sudo and also manage installed packages. One drawback (or maybe not?) is that you have to install packages for each node version separately.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works. Where I disagree is with using `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. `~/.bashrc` is used for only non-login shells and `~/.bash_profile` is used for login shells.

I advise you export to `$PATH` in `~/.profile` which will be available to the whole desktop session.

Therefore, you should add something like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/[user]/npm/bin
```

to `~/.profile` for best results

Answer (score 0):

normaly when you got this error it means you dont have ember-cli installed. or you have installed with sudo.