# ubuntu 18.04- ember: command not found

Tags: javascript, bash, ember.js, path, failed-installation

I know this has been addressed before, but I've tried the advice on [No command 'ember' found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650231/no-command-ember-found) and it hasn't worked for me.

I'm trying to install EmberJs for a techtest and I keep getting 'Command 'ember' not found'. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and have checked all my paths as follows.

When I run npm install -g ember-cli it installs and shows:

```
npm WARN deprecated exists-sync@0.0.4: Please replace with usage of 
fs.existsSync
/home/[user]/.npm-global/bin/ember -> 
/home/[user]/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
+ ember-cli@3.5.0
updated 1 package in 14.662s
```

So I've definitely got it installed.
When I run which npm/ which node I get the following respectively:

```
/usr/bin/npm
/usr/bin/node
```

When I run echo $PATH I get:

```
/home/[user]/npm_global/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/
bin:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/
ruby-2.3.7/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/
sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/
share/rvm/bin
```

Andddd I have these paths in my bashrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```

and

```
export PATH="/home/[user]/npm_global/bin:$PATH"
```

I realise this is a lot of info, I'm new to this so wanted to give as much as I could. Any suggestions very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: have you tried nvm? it's a node version manager that sets up your paths for you, that way, when you do npm install -g ember-cli, you'll properly have access to the globally installed bins

Comment: It seems that you have `/home/[user]/npm_global/bin` in your `PATH` but your first snipped tells it was installed in `/home/[user]/.npm-global/bin/ember` (notice the dot).

Comment: @swapgs thanks, good spot! however, i've added the dot to my path, restarted my terminal and it's still not recognising ember :/

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli when you say use nvm, what would i use it for exactly? would i run nvm install instead of npm?

Comment: Can you please run `ls -l /home/[user]/.npm-global/bin/ember` and tell us if the file exists? If not, `find /home/[user]/ -type f -name ember`.

Comment: Ran the command, the file definitely exists

Comment: Nah, NVM is a set-up time utility. After you install node and npm with it, you use npm as usual

Answer (score 1):

The error you are experiencing means that `ember` is not in the path. It's really irrelevant if you've installed with `npm` or downloaded the files manually for the purposes of properly setting up your path. When you encounter a PATH issue the solution is quite simple.

1. Find the executable. `find / -name ember` if you want to include symlinks, or just `find -type f -name ember` if you want only the actual location (npm installs will install in their own managed directory and then symlink to the typical location for binary files such as `/usr/local/bin` on macOS)
2. Once found, use your shell's properties file like `bashrc` to append the directory containing the executable to the `$PATH` variable.

It's as simple as that. Binary files that are found in your `$PATH` can be executed. Make sure you see the path to `ember` there, or manually add the full path that you find in step 1 to your `$PATH` in `bashrc` with `export PATH=$PATH_TO_DIR_WITH_EMBER_BIN:$PATH` which concatenates to the existing `$PATH` variable